Optimized algorithms for correlation based feature elimination
Context: I have a large dataframe with close to a million rows and 2000 columns. I'm trying to do feature elimination using the correlation between the variables. The problem of course is that for a set of n features, we need the correlation between nC2 or n*(n-1)/2 combinations, making it an inherently O(n^2) operation.
Underlying data: all numerical only.
So I want to know if we can optimize this using some divide and conquer strategy as follows:

calculate correlation between 20 batches of 100 columns each
eliminate the highly correlated features (threshold > 95%)
combine the remaining features (say about 1000), divide into 20 batches again
repeat the above process until we reach a fixed column threshold (that we can process together, say 200)
calculate correlation for the final time from this and drop the correlated features

I wanted to know if this method would work, or if there are further optimized methods we can use for this purpose. I also want to know if this would work for different types of correlations, like spearman, kendall, etc.
Hypothesis: This method makes this important assumption:

if f1 and f2 are >95% correlated, f2 and f3 are also >95% correlated, then we assume f1 and f3 are also >95% correlated.

I'm not sure if there is a concrete theoretical basis for this, and would like to hear your thoughts on how to prove it for different types of correlations.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Please edit the question to say more about why you want to do the feature elimination. On this site, the more information you provide about the underlying data and hypotheses, the more likely you are to get a helpful answer. Also, the type of approach you suggest would only identify pairwise correlations and miss other collinearities that principal components might identify. There are tools for identifying the top principal components of data sets of this scale; see this paper, for example.
